# Do using Smile library over H2O is good idea on the scale of performances?

Tags: scala, h2o, smile

Walkthrough of Smile performance as compared to H2O.
Smile - Statistical Machine Intelligence and Learning Engine.
I Want to use Smile library for Constructing Pipeline using word2vec model.

Comment: Your submission is very generic without clear explanation of the problem you want SO to assist. You can use both H2O and SMILE to build a word2vec model so where is your problem?

Comment: Wanna evaluate the performances of both H2O and SMILE  using F1 score for particular dataset using scala,I want to know if it is done before using the parameter which are word2vec model,h2o or smile and scala.It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use H2O [word2vec](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/word2vec.html) algorithm you can use Sparkling Water samples [here](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/tree/d04366c4f73f4bedfe1d1543009a850a1bdbeded/examples/scripts) which are writing in Scala/Java, very easy to make them work on your Scala code.

I don't have much experience with [SMILE](https://github.com/haifengl/smile) library however looking their code you can find some of the Java samples in their test code [here](https://github.com/haifengl/smile/tree/master/nlp/src/test/java/smile/nlp) into nlp section. You can try them to use with Scala as well.

I hope you know what you want to do because they way you describe your question is not exactly clear. What you really need is to ask a very specific question after writing some code first. This will help you to understand exactly where you are stuck and what is needed to unblock you.